# Check of PDN for RF Amplifier

Tags: power-supply, rf, ldo, step-down

I would like to ask you for help with the power delivery network (PDN) design.

[image]

For optimal working conditions, [HMC863ALC4TR](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc863alc4.pdf) needs Vdd = 5.5 V and Vgg = -0.75 V. I have tried to design such a network to provide the closest possible voltages. The input voltage is regulated with [TL5209DR](https://www.ti.com/product/TL5209/part-details/TL5209DR) to 5.65 V. This is then stepped down and inverted with [LTC1983ES6-3#TRMPBF](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1983fc.pdf) to -3 V and with additional LDO ([ADP7183](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adp7183.pdf), although the schematic contains the -1.2 V version I am using the -1 V one) it is regulated to -1 V.

The output current of [TL5209DR](https://www.ti.com/product/TL5209/part-details/TL5209DR) is 500 mA, and the Idd = 350 mA.
I have never designed such a complicated PDN. I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: Humphrey Appleby - Hi, Stack Exchange is not a "good fit" for a changing question. You are not allowed to change the question in a way that obsoletes / invalidates existing answer(s), as it makes them look incomplete, even though they were valid when written. (See the term "chameleon question" on Meta.SE.) Therefore I have rolled-back your later changes to this question, to the state where you received an answer. || I recommend you follow [this article](/help/someone-answers) to effectively close *this* question.

Comment: (continued) Then ask a new question with your updated schematic (which you can copy from the edit history of this question), include a link to *this* question for context, explain what changes you made *and why*. Then ask a specific question. A question which just asks for help and advice is at risk of being closed as "needs focus" (a.k.a. "too broad") as there is no specific question which can be judged for correctness. (In the past, design review questions were not allowed, due to being too open-ended. It would help if you can point to a *specific* area of concern in your design.)

Comment: I was unsure if I could repost the same problem twice (though significantly modified). 
I also wanted this post to be actual so I could refer to it when I asked others outside of StackExchange for help. Therefore, I edited it. Finally, I thought that it would be more helpful for people looking for advice on the topic to see the final design, not the one containing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts about this design:

1. The voltage inverter contains a regulator, so there is no need to provide a positive supply voltage matching the desired negative output voltage. The maximum recommended input voltage is 5.5 V, so any voltage between 3.3 V and 5.5 V would be OK here.
2. The impedance of the voltage divider R3/R4 is far too high. The datasheet specifies 60 µA maximum supply current, but for a safe startup you must provide much more. There is 1 mA of load current in the LED path, 2 mA supply current in the negative voltage LDO and 2.5 mA into the VG input (see figure "Igg vs. Input Power"). Many capacitors will also draw additional startup current. I would provide at least 20 mA.
3. There is a problem in the power sequence. VG is initially 0 V and the VDD ramps up long before VG is in the required range. As I understand the datasheet, during this startup time the RF amplifier will draw a dangerous high current > 700 mA (see figure "Idd vs. Vgg1"). This current cannot be provided by the TL5209 and it will probably go into current limit and finally thermal shutdown. It is not possible to feed the voltage inverter from the TL5209 output, you must control the EN pin of the LDO in a way, that it is only enabled if VG is ready.
4. The VG input draws a variable current depending on the RF input power between 0 and 2.5 mA. So the high impedance voltage divider R5/R6 will not work. You need the adjustable version ADP7183ACPZN-R7 here to directly create the correct VG.
5. You feed the /SHDN input of the voltage inverter the hard way directly from VDD which exceeds the recommended conditions. It is seldom a good idea to provide a signal input voltage, that is far above the supply voltage of an IC. Input protection diodes may conduct with unwanted side effects.

What is you VIN? If you can specify this, there may be another solution than this regulator mass grave.
A control loop, that measures Idd and regulates VG accordingly, would be much better.

Comment: This is my project aimed at educational purposes. The VIN will be generated from the DC source and higher than the VDD (_e. g._ 9 V - 16 V).
Ad 1/ I noticed the input voltage range for the inverter being up to 5.5 V, but I did not want to run it up to limits. Therefore I have added a voltage divider.
Ad 2/ If I understand correctly, changing the values of resistors by a few orders lower will work. Or not?
Ad 3/ As I mentioned, my project is not targeted at practical usage. Could I solve this problem by adding a jumper between LDO's EN pin and the controlling voltage?

Comment: Ad 2 and 3/ To eliminate the low output current problem, I must select a different input LDO (_i. e._ any with output current capability higher than 1 A). Is that right?
Ad 5/ Can you please elaborate more on this one? Is the problem that I feed /SHDN with a voltage higher than the input voltage of this IC?

Comment: @HumphreyAppleby 2) yes, changing the values of resistors by a few orders lower will work. 3) No, since the -3 is not generated if EN is disabled, there will be no VG as well. It is dangerous for the RF amp if VD is present before VG. You don't need to provide more than 500 mA, but you should avoid a situation where the amp draws more. 5) Yes, just connect /SHND to VIN of this regulator to avoid problems. At 16 V VIN the linear regulator must dissipate around 5 W. This would be far too much for an SO8 case.

Comment: A laboratory source will generate the input voltage. So I could set it as low as possible concerning input LDO. However, as this LDO still has to be changed, I can select one with a better package. If I understand you correctly, I can eliminate the rest of the problems by adding jumpers between the Vg and Vd pins of the amplifier and manually connecting those pins in the corresponding order to power up the amplifier.