# Check of PDN for RF Amplifier - Revised

Tags: power-supply, rf, ldo, step-down

This is an update to my previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672094/check-of-pdn-for-rf-amplifier). I was recommended to post it again.

[image]

For optimal working conditions, [HMC863ALC4TR](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc863alc4.pdf) needs Vdd = 5.5 V and Vgg = -0.75 V. I have tried to design such a network to provide the closest possible voltages. The input voltage is regulated with [ADM7171ACPZ-5.0-R7](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm7171.pdf) to 5.5 V. This is then stepped down and inverted with [LTC1983ES6-3#TRMPBF](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1983fc.pdf) to -3 V and with additional LDO ([ADP7183](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adp7183.pdf), although the schematic contains the -1.2 V version I am using the -1 V one) it is regulated to -1 V.

The output current of [TL5209DR](https://www.ti.com/product/TL5209/part-details/TL5209DR) is 500 mA, and the Idd = 350 mA.

SMA connectors are just placeholders at this moment.

Comment: explain what changes you have made, and why, and then ask a question

Comment: Humphrey Appleby - Hi, "*I was recommended to post it again.*" I did *not* say to "post it again". You tried to change your previous question after people had already provided answers. That "moving of the goalposts" creates big problems here, if changes are made to a question which invalidate existing answers. Please read all the previous advice. || If you are trying to give a final solution *without asking a new question* (that wasn't clear from the attempted edit to your previous question), then you can write your own *answer* below your previous question (don't change the question). Thanks.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have made the changes proposed in my previous post. This is an updated schematic with updated description. Mentioning these changes at this new question is irrelevant and could cause confusion. Therefore, I have only added a link to the previous post.

Comment: @SamGibson You commented my previous question that I should not edit it too much and ask a new question on modified schematic instead. If I have misinterpreted your answer, I am sorry.